# Configure and restart wlan0 network interface with uap0 interface without disrupting connection to uap0

Tags: networking, systemd

I have two network interfaces, `wlan0` and `uap0` currently set up. I am using `uap0` as WiFi access point that a user's WiFi device can connect to and be used to configure the `wlan0` interface via a Web UI hosted on the pi.

I have the configuration through the Web UI working as a proof of concept but it requires restarting services which results in the `uap0` accesses point closing and kicks the user's device off that WiFi connection.

I would like to find a method that does not require restarting services associated with both `wlan0` and `uap0` since I need to preserve the connection to `uap0` after setting up the `wlan0` interface.

I have looked at `systemd networkd` a bit but I am unsure if this behavior is possible or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't include uap0 in whatever service you are referring to, and instead start it through some custom service.

Comment: Are there any resources that you can link regarding setting up a custom service for a network interface? I am currently using a script to set up uap0 and I am not sure exactly what all that it is doing with regards to wlan0.

Comment: It's all about **systemd**; this is what plays the role of [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) in most contemporary GNU/Linux systems.  It has been around a bit longer than the Pi and of course not unique to it.  RpiOS is only a few tweaks on normative Debian, and systemd is pretty much the same everywhere, so if you are searching for documentation search "linux systemd" (or just "system"), including "Raspberry Pi" will just hamstring the searches.   It is not hard to create a service if you already have a script that works, just a little trial and error with the service file....

Comment: ...You could always post the script here or on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and ask for advice about creating the service.  How exactly you are setting up the AP is relevant.

Comment: My understanding is that systemd networkd is easier to use with wired connections and while wireless connections can be set up it seems that it is suggested to use something a bit more powerful like Network Manager instead. Any suggestions on which toolset to use?

Comment: Probably a bad idea to use several different monolithic networking services.  I have never heard of this contrast WRT wired vs. wireless  (but that doesn't mean it isn't true).   Currently I do my own networking using `dhcpcd` and hook scripts (see `man dhcpcd-run-hooks`), but I don't recommend that here.   I'm not currently running any AP's but I do periodically using `hostapd`; an AP, especially one with no uplink, is pretty much its own thing and need not relate or be involved with other networking configuration.  This is why I recommend you use whatever you like for the normal...

Comment: ...inet connected wlan0 interface and run the AP using something else. That also separate any issues you have -- the wlan0 configuration would be exactly the same as if you did not have a second wifi running an AP, and problems with the AP have nothing to do with wlan0.  BTW, I have noticed using the built-in wifi and a wifi adapter sometimes does not work very well (using the same frequencies and channels will probably make that worse).  I've resorted to putting the adapter on a USB extension cable before (although I would not go so far as to say that is a definite requirement).